# Firefox add-on won't open its own file as a new xul window.

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

My add-on creates a FireFox File menu command that triggers callback function 'launchApp'.

```
function launchApp() {
   var ww = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
                   .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);
   var appUrl='chrome://mrT2/mrT00.xul';            // production  (fails)
   var appUrl='file:///C:/mpa/@@mrT-2.0/mrT00.xul'; // testing     (works)
   var win = ww.openWindow(null, appUrl, "mrT2-window", "chrome,resizable", null);
   // Summary of  results of ww.openWindow() for various appUrl values:
   // 'chrome:///mrT2/mrT00.xul' 'No chrome package registered for ...' (true)
   // 'chrome://mrT00.xul'        'Invalid chrome URI: /'           (true)
   // 'chrome:///mrT00.xul'  and 'chrome://mrT2/mrT00.xul' seem valid yet both give:
   //Error: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 ...
   // ...  (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIWindowWatcher.openWindow]       (unexplained)
return true;
```

The above code works nicely and is great for testing mrT00.xul (because it collects the file directly from where I am editing it).

However when I interchange the two appUrl vars to try and open the exact same file as shipped via the xpi (and now internal to firefox) I get the dreaded 'illegal value' 0x80070057.

After 2 long days of research and study I cannot fault my code. Can you?

Otherwise, how may I begin tracing nsiWindowWatcher to pinpoint the error?

Comment: What about `chrome://mrT2/content/mrT00.xul`?

Comment: thank you sir. Now we get a different and even more fascinating result!

Comment: Let me guess, a transparent window? :)

Comment: Log now shows `No chrome package registered for chrome://mrt2/content/mrT00.xul` (The package name has been mutilated but the filename is still mixed case). I added a new log message AFTER the openWIndow to display the new appUrl value and it yielded: `mrT2: opened chrome://mrT2/content/mrT00.xul window=[object ChromeWindow]` (yes, I did move the goodies from root .xpi to a new /content subdirectory)

Comment: That would be an issue with the `chrome.manifest` file then.

Comment: The solution was indeed to create a 1-line chrome.manifest containing `content  mrT2  content/`. The omission occurred as a result of enhancing an existing bootstrapped extension (which had not previously required one). The application cannot now natively access localStorage but the original question been answered and will be closed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad things can happen when an extension attempts to open a xul file outside the /content directory or inside it when the chrome.manifest file in the .xpi root is not in order. Firefox handling of both these situations is not above reproach, warnings being offered in neither case.